# How to correctly develop a PHP contact form?

Tags: php, html, email, contact-form

I see a lot of questions are already being asked about creating a working PHP contact form and I'm struggling too, that's why I've been looking on the internet for a very simple PHP form. I've found one, configured it, but I don't receive any mail why I'm 100% sure it should! Can you find the bug?

I have included the HTML and PHP code in this topic, but you can find a live demo and the code right here: http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Message</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

    <table width="450px">

        <tr>

            <td valign="top">

                <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>

            </td>

            <td valign="top">

                <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td valign="top"">

            <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>

            </td>

            <td valign="top">

                <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td valign="top">

                <label for="email">Email Address *</label>

            </td>

            <td valign="top">

                <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td valign="top">

                <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>

            </td>

            <td valign="top">

                <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td valign="top">

                <label for="comments">Comments *</label>

            </td>

            <td valign="top">

                <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>

            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">

                <input type="submit" value="Submit">   <a href="http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php">Email Form</a>

            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
```

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

```
// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "PCRebels@hotmail.com";

$email_subject = "Test email form";





function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

}



// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');

}



$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



$error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}



$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
```

// create email headers

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: @Keerthi Nope, no errors :/

Comment: Why are you supreseing errors from mail() with the @..?  Surely that defeats the object..?  Remove the @ and output the results of mail()

Comment: @ChrisMaggs it seems this might be a solution, now I receive this error: Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in D:\Documenten\Semester 2\Web\HEREXAMEN\WEBSITE\Server\root\send_form_email.php on line 137 

So I guess it's working now but I need to configure some kind of SMTP to be able to send the email? How do I need to configure this, I'm running it now on a local webserver (USB Webserver)

Comment: I don't think that USB Webserver has a mail server built into it. To send the mail to google's mail server, use these credentials [Digitial Ocean SMTP tut](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server)

Comment: Does your USB Webserver have a built in SMTP server..?  I'm guessing No.

Comment: @ChrisMaggs I need indeed a SMTP server, after uploading it to my webhost, everything is working fine. Thanks for the help!